# How to simply import KML file in Google Map on webpage

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

So I have maps generated in Maps Engine Pro, exported their KML files as I have read that is what you do to create custom maps in the Maps API.

Here is some butchered code that i tried to put together that i just cannot seem to get to work, but essentially all i am trying to figure out is to display a simple map that is not just a link to the Maps Engine so that it can be manipulated later one(like clustering and such)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>


        var map;
        var src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/westcampus.kml';

        function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.257753, -90.823688),
                zoom: 2,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            });
            loadKmlLayer(src, map);
        }

        function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
            var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
                suppressInfoWindows: true,
                preserveViewport: false,
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function (event) {
                var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
                var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
                testimonial.innerHTML = content;
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>


<body>
    <div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One option is a third party parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/westcampus.kml) (clustering 3 markers doesn't make sense...) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/).  You can't access the information in a KmlLayer except when the user clicks on it.  Note, however that a third party parser is not a good solution if your KML is complex.

Comment: the real map i want to do has about 14,000 markers....clustering would be nice

Comment: KmlLayer will render the data using tiles, if the KML can be rendered by KmlLayer, you might not need clustering.  A third party parser will have to download and parse that KML in order to cluster it, there probably will be a performance hit.

Comment: thank you for your help, i greatly appreciate it, and obviously im pretty green here, but either way is there any simple way of taking data from a map and put in a website without just iframing(using their embed button) it? it jsut looks bad adn there is no way of customizing it...